# Center Google Maps InfoWindow On Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having a problem centering my InfoWindow on page load. On load, the map is centering on the marker, which puts the InfoWindow off screen (I'm working with a short height for my map container).

Now clicking the marker does re-center the map on the InfoWindow so that it looks exactly like I want. That being the case, I've even tried firing the marker.click trigger to achieve a solution on load, but had no luck. What am I missing?

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/q9NTS/7/**

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var marker;
    var infoWindow;
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
        setLocation();
    }

    function setLocation() {
        var address = '@(Model.Event.Address)' + ', ' + '@(Model.Event.City)' + ', ' + '@(Model.Event.State)' + ' ' + '@(Model.Event.Zip)';
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var position = results[0].geometry.location;
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: position,
                    title: '@(Model.Event.Venue)'
                });
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

                var content = 'blah';
                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: content
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

                //infoWindow.open(map, marker); doesn't work
                google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); //still doesn't work
            }
            else {
                //
            }
        });
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You apparently just need to wait longer before triggering the click event.

```
// wait until the map is idle.
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // wait some more (...)
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click'); //still doesn't work
  },2000);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mhs9L/2/)

Comment: That worked, although I made the wait time a bit shorter. Thank you for the suggestion. I'd be interested in something cleaner but I will definitely go with this for now.

Comment: I don't particularly like it either. With the new event driven v3 API, there _should_ be an event to tell when everything is complete and triggering the click event will work correctly, but if there is, it isn't well advertized.